# How to add a name attribute to a dynamically generated <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic, html-table

I have been looking all around through numerous sources to try and find a way to add `name=""` to generated table rows. Here is the table part of the form being submitted.

```
<table id="quote_form_table"border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;width:100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>

        </tr>
        <tr name="row[]">
         <td><input type="text" name="quantity" ></td>
         <td>
           <select name="products">
              <option>Roller banner</option>
              <option>Grasshopper</option>
              <option>Pop up display</option>
            </select>
         </td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option>Roller banner</option>
            <option>Grasshopper</option>
            <option>Pop up display</option>
          </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
  <button type="button"onclick="addrow()">Add Row</button>
  <button type="button"onclick="removerow()">Remove Row</button><br><br><br>
```

Here is the script adding and removing rows.

```
   <script>
    function addrow() {
        var table = document.getElementById("quote_form_table");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quantity" >';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<select name="products"><option>Roller banner</option><option>GrassHopper</option><option>Pop up display</option></select>';
        cell3.innerHTML = '<select name="type"><option>Roller banner</option><option>GrassHopper</option><option>Pop up display</option></select>';

    }
    function removerow() {
          document.getElementById("quote_form_table").deleteRow(-1);
    }
   </script>
```

As a novice at Javascript ,(and I use the term 'novice' very loosely as it is not a language I am familiar with to fix this myself), I tried setAttribute to no avail.

```
var tr = tr.setAttribute("name", "row[]", 0);
```

I found many sources on how to add classes or Id's but none for 'name'. So as a wild stab in the dark I tried a last attempt to see if I could work it out.

```
row.name = "row[]";
```

So now here I am.

The table rows are being made into arrays for PHP to process so that the information can be sent off in an email for price quotes and I can generate the information on the other end in the right order.

My question is How do you add a `name="row[]"` to the dynamically generated tr tag?

Is it even possible?

Comment: `name` is not a useful attribute for `<tr>` elements. Either `id` or `class` would be more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add `name` to new rows, right?

```
var numRow = 0;

function addrow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("quote_form_table");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    row.setAttribute("name", "row"+numRow);
    numRow++;
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quantity" >';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<select name="products"><option>Roller banner</option><option>GrassHopper</option><option>Pop up display</option></select>';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<select name="type"><option>Roller banner</option><option>GrassHopper</option><option>Pop up display</option></select>';
}

function removerow() {
    document.getElementById("quote_form_table").deleteRow(-1);
    numRow--;
}
```

But i think that you should use `id` or `class` instead of name for `<tr>` elements

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reason for the name is because the table is being used as part of a web-form. So I am using the 'name' to $_POST so I can process the information inputted with PHP to then send the email with the information on.

Comment: @SamCraddock - table rows are not form controls. Giving them a name attribute will not cause them to participate in a form submission.

Comment: @Alohci Right yes I understand now what you mean.Sorry for my ignorance.